# Piping cat output into a Java jar through the terminal

Tags: java, jar, pipe

I have a JAR file that will require use of the standard input. I need to use this command and cannot change it:

```
cat filename | java -jar jarname.jar
```

I want this to be accessible to the JAR somehow, easiest way being through `String[] args`. The problem is that this the result of `cat filename` doesn't show up in `String[] args`, or in any way for me to make use of it. I've tried searching this up for some time, but all I get is questions pertaining to writing java output to files using the pipe.

Comment: You are piping to a *process* which happens to be running a JVM, not to a jar file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> easiest way being through `String[] args`

impossible.

The file will be available as `System.in`.

Here's a trivial program that prints sysin right back out, adding line numbers visually. `cat` with extra steps. Now you know how to use System.in. Note, if System.in contains byte-based data, obviously don't wrap it in readers (which are for char based data). Just read bytes straight from it.

```
> cat Test.java
import java.io.*;

class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    var in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int lineNum = 1;
    while (true) {
      String line = in.readLine();
      if (line == null) break;
      System.out.printf("%6d. %s\n", lineNum++, line);
    }
  }
}

> cat hello.txt
Hello!
World!
> cat hello.txt | java Test.java
     1. Hello!
     2. World!
```